# Why the padding changed when resize window using css and bootstrap on rails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have no idea why the body padding-top will change when I maximize the window and resize the window.

Is there anyway to fix the black navbar fix on the top?

and the navbar menu dropdown in the follwing

and the the content . and they don't overlap each other, whatever you change the window size.

Thanks in advance

css code / html code in gist
https://gist.github.com/poc7667/6505299

*Max the window
[image]
*half the window
[image]

Comment: please include some code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding !important - If there is some rogue CSS causing this issue, this should overwrite it.

```
body {
    padding-top: 0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your code..

but usual you can fix the navigation to the top with:

`.navigation {

position: absolute;

top: 0px;

}`

The wrapper:

`#wrapper {

position: relative;

}`

in HTML:

`<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="navigation"></div>

</div>`

dont forget to clear/ reset the body with:

`body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}`

A helpful tool to debug your webcode is the browsers html/css-inspector.
You can check the code before and after resizing.